# Replace break line with '\n'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I need help for replacing line breaks in my mysql database with \n.
If I copy mysql text and past in MS Word, I have this:

[image: image 1]

I need to replace the break lines with \n. Like this:

[image: image 2]

There are any MySql command for this and one PHP or Javascript function?

Thank You.

Comment: I don't have -ve permission, but -ve!

Comment: Php function `nl2br(...)`

Comment: Is this an april fools joke? Paste in notepad, forget about Word.

Comment: I have showed in Microsoft Word just for example, to see the line breaks...

Comment: `"\n"` is a line break character, `"\\n"` is the string `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Php there is a function named `nl2br`

```
 echo nl2br("hello\nWorld");
```

and the result is

```
 hello<br/>World
```

In sql there is a function named `REPLACE`

```
   UPDATE yourtable SET field=REPLACE(REPLACE(field, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

And Finally in javaScript you have `replace` too

```
myString = myString.replace(/\r?\n/g, "");
```

Good Luck

Comment: read more about this function http://au2.php.net/nl2br

Comment: Thank you but I don’t need replace ‘\n’ to html ‘<br/>’. I just need to replace line breaks with ‘\n’ character.

Comment: see my edited answer, now you have all three functions(`Php`,`Sql` and `javaScript`)...

Answer (score 1):

If MS Word is parsing the text with linebreaks, it means it already has them.

Use a text editor like notepad++ and set it to show all characters. You will see what special chars are being used as linebreaks (it might be \n, \r and a mix of both).

They won't show up when you browse your database with phpmyadmin, because its textarea control will parse the linebreaks for you.

Comment: Thank you but I don’t need replace ‘\n’ to html ‘<br/>’. I just need to replace line breaks with ‘\n’ character.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your input string correctly, but if, the code would look like this.

```
  function replace_lb($str){
    return str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '\n', $str );
  }
```

Usage:

```
  $query = mysql_query('SELECT `id`,`value` FROM table ', $link);
  while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    mysql_query('UPDATE table SET `value`= "'.replace_lb($result['value']).'" WHERE id="'.$result['id'].'"', $link);
  }
```

The code could use some optimalization, but I think it will suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

try the php nl2br

```
<?php
$result = nl2br($row['MYSQL_RESULT']);  // from the return from your query
?>
```

Comment: Thank you but I don’t need replace ‘\n’ to html ‘<br/>’. I just need to replace line breaks with ‘\n’ character.