# Remove multiple line breaks (\n) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

We have an onboarding form for new employees with multiple newlines (4-5 between lines) that need stripped.  I want to get rid of the extra newlines but still space out the blocks with one \n.

example:

```
New employee<br/>
John Doe

Employee Number<br/>
1234
```

I'm currently using `text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/g, '$1');` but that gets rid of all newlines without spacing.

Comment: Why don't you wrap text in tags instead?

Comment: javascript is in the end http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784943/replace-break-line-with-n/22785036#22785036

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2,}/g, '$1\n');
```

use this, it will remove newlines where there are at least 2 or more

**update**

on specific requirement of the OP I will edit the answer a bit.

```
text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2}/g, '$1').replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){3,}/g, '$1\n');
```

Comment: If I understand the requirements correctly, that's not what's wanted: http://regex101.com/r/dA1tP5

Comment: Oh yes, that works, and it's much simpler than mine... http://regex101.com/r/jC5aI4

Comment: Thanks.  The problem is there are single newlines between "New Employee" and "John Doe" then there are several newlines until the next value.  It's all random.  So I want to preserve one line break and get rid of any 2+ line breaks.  http://regex101.com/r/zC8pS7

Comment: aint you getting the expected result ?

Comment: you can ofcourse fiddle with the numbers in the last quatifier `{2,}` to get your expected o/p. try changing it to 1 or 3 and see what happens, I just want to help you to learn a bit here :)

Comment: So basically I want "If 2 /n replace with 1" then "If 3+ /n replace with 2"  Sorry I wasn't more specific in the original question

Answer (score 17):

We can tidy up the regex as follows:

```
text = text.replace(/[\r\n]{2,}/g, "\n");
```